# How to filter multiple values in Sharepoint REST API query?

Tags: rest, sharepoint

What is the proper syntax for determining if multiple values are present in a Sharepoint list using REST API call?

**Example**:

```html
https://mycompany.sharepoint.com/sites/test/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('BigLis')/items?$filter=ProjectNo eq '123', '141', '154'
```

I want to know if any records have a ProjectNo of 123, 141 or 154. There doesn't seem to be an "OR" operator in ODATA.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using the REST API below.

```
/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('BigLis')/items?$filter=(ProjectNo eq '123' or ProjectNo eq '141' or ProjectNo eq '154')
```